# How to solve natural language inference using SentenceBERT?

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

How can I solve natural language inference using fine-tuned SentenceBERT models(ex. [sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2 · Hugging Face](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2)) to obtain better sentence vectors?

Many of these models have been fine-tuned using natural language inference datasets such as SNLI, but can I fine-tune these models again with SNLI?

I asked the question because many of the applications using SetenceBERT are better sentence vector-based search and clustering, and I could not find an application for natural language inference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can fine-tune these SentenceBERT models again on the SNLI dataset. This could potentially lead to better performance in natural language inference tasks. However, keep in mind that the fine-tuning process could take a long time depending on the size of the model and the amount of data you are using. It's important to keep track of your model's performance by evaluating it on a validation set. You can also try using other natural language inference datasets for fine-tuning to see if it improves performance in your specific use case.